# How to initiate GMAIL Api Authentication on client side?

Tags: c#, .net, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have an application handled by a server to request a huge amount of emails (10-30k emails), but when there is the authentication with google from the API, the window is opened on the server but not on the client.
To simplify the request is made locally (so on the server) .

So how can I make a request on the server and get the google's authenticate window on the client ?

here is my code:

```
Public Bool Connect()
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream;
    GoogleClientSecrets googleClientSecrets;
    string credentialPath;
    List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
    UserCredential userCredential;

    try
    {
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream(credentialKeyFile);
        googleClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(memoryStream);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    try
    {
        credentialPath = Path.Combine(credentialsPath, account);
        scopes.Add(GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom);
        userCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            googleClientSecrets.Secrets,
            scopes.ToArray(),
            account + ".json",
            CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credentialPath, true) 
                        ).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (userCredential == null)
    {
        GlobalMethods.AddLog("L'authentification à l'API Google a échoué.");
        return false;
    }
    try
    {
        accountGmailService = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = userCredential
        });
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (accountGmailService == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
                return true;
}
```

Comment: Is this an asp.net application? It's not quite clear

Comment: not an ASP.net, but C# app

Comment: If its an app then the user needs to install it on their machine and then you can use the code you have.   If you want this hosted then you should be using asp .net and release it as a web app.

Comment: Yup yesterdays question was deleted.   Before i had a chance to explain to him what the issue is.  Even after OP edited his question and added the code i requested. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64573922/1841839  I have no idea why he keeps getting -1 on this its a valid question

Comment: The auestion was has been deleted yesterday so I asked it once again with more details

Comment: "The auestion was has been deleted yesterday"...but only because you yourself deleted it! The others are saying that it wasn't really necessary to do that, as an answer had been provided. If you needed to clarify you could always have edited that question instead. Then people don't have to answer the same thing twice!

Comment: @ADyson They deleted it after an admin hammer closed the question as needing debugging details.    Which was twenty minutes after they had edited  it and added the information i had asked for and i had answered it.    If anything admin hammer close was the issue here.

Comment: @DaImTo agreed that was unhelpful, seems like maybe the admin didn't really read it properly. I see that happen a lot unfortunately.  But it could still have been re-opened. Anyway it's done now, this question is fine as-is.

Answer (score 2):

GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is designed for use with installed applications it will open the authorization and authentication screen on the machine the code is running on.

There is no way to have a server sided app run and ask a user to connect the user needs to initiate the connection.  The only way to do that would be to deploy this as a web application and use the following code.

For web applications you should be using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow and found in the following example  [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc)  It will cause the authorization window to open on the users web browser rather then the servers.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4
{
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
}
```